# Both mp3 and ogg with jQuery jPlayer in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, jplayer

I'm trying to develop an online music jukebox (kind of "deezer like", I made a small video : http://www.le-guevel.com/player.ogv). 
I am using jQuery jPlayer to read the music on the browser side, but I am facing a problem with firefox : it does not read my mp3 files.

I know that mozilla refuses to implement it because of patent reasons. I also know that jPlayer should fallback to a flash solution to read mp3. 
The problem is I actually read files in different formats (mostly mp3 and ogg). And from what I can see in jPlayer source code (~l.640 in the 2.1.0 version) :

```
    // If jPlayer is supporting any format in a solution, then the solution is used.
    this.html.used = false;
    this.flash.used = false;
    $.each(this.solutions, function(solutionPriority, solution) {
      $.each(self.formats, function(formatPriority, format) {
        if(self[solution].support[format]) {
          self[solution].used = true;
            return false;
        }
      });
    });
```

the player decides to use either html5 or flash (not both). So as I initialize jPlayer with both ogg and mp3, the player decides to use html5 (ogg is supported). I could change the priority of the 
solutions (html and flash). But if I put flash to highest priority, the player won't play my ogg files because the flash binary of jPlayer does not support ogg.

Is there any way I can get it to work ?

The easiest solution would be of course to encode all my files in the same format but I would prefer not to.
The second solution would be to force firefox to read mp3. I know firefox can read mp3 with external plugins : I installed gecko-mediaplayer on my debian and I can read mp3 files on firefox. But is it 
compatible with html5 ?
The third solution would be to edit the jPlayer flash plugin to make it support ogg. But I know nothing about Actionscript programming, and I would prefer using html5...
And the last solution would be to use another browser (like chromium) but I am used to firefox and would prefer to keep it.

As you can imagine, I would prefer something like the second solution but I'm not sure it is feasible. Could someone please help me?

Thanks :) (an sorry for my probably bad english).